# How do I display a multi-value field in a repeat?

Tags: xpages

I'm attempting to display the values of a multi-value field as an unordered list on my XPage. Unfortunately, when doing this with documents which do not already have the bound field, I'm informed **'rowData' not found** for my itemValueArray. I had created a document prior to these machinations that has values in the field, so that one still opens for me.

Where have I gone wrong?

```
<xp:div style="display:none;">
    <xp:inputText id="linkages" value="#{poDoc.Linkages}" multipleTrim="true" multipleSeparator=";">
    </xp:inputText>
</xp:div>
<ul>
    <xp:repeat id="linkagesDisplayRepeat" rows="30" var="rowData">  
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var linkages = poDoc.getItemValueArray("Linkages");
return linkages;}]]></xp:this.value>
        <li>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField7">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData;}]]>
                </xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
        </li>
    </xp:repeat>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Error **'rowData' not found** is caused by non-existing item "Linkages".

Render the ul-repeat-block only if item "Linkages" is in document

```xml
   <xp:panel rendered="#{javascript: poDoc.hasItem('Linkages')}">
      <ul>
         <xp:repeat
            ...
         </xp:repeat>
      </ul>
   </xp:panel>
```

As an alternative you could set a default value to document's item "Linkages" on beforePageLoad event:

```xml
   <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:
         if (!poDoc.hasItem("Linkages")) {
            poDoc.replaceItemValue("Linkages", "defaultValue");
         }
   }]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```

Answer (score 1):

similar to knut's second idea, you could test for a value during data binding. if there is no value, return a default array (e.g., ["data missing"]). otherwise, return the field's value(s). this way you don't have to force a value into the otherwise empty or absent field...unless that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple EL for hide the repeat:

```
<xp:repeat id="linkagesDisplayRepeat" rows="30" var="rowData"
    rendered="#{not empty poDoc.Linkages}">
```